# Deploying both Flask app and Node.js app to heroku one git repo

Tags: github, heroku, procfile

I have a repository and I want to deploy two application from it. I have it set up as two different applications in Heroku.

Im using a Procfile to load the Flask application and it deploys properly however when the Node application deploys it also tries to use the Procfile instead of using the Node buildpack i have loaded.

Is there a way to fix this other than separating the repositories?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple workers in your Procfile.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#more-process-type-examples

```
web: python main.py
app: npm start
```

However bear in mind an app can only have one active web worker. The flask app will probably use a port. And your node application will likely as well. In my example the `app` worker cannot open a port! **If that is the case you need to host your repo on 2 separate Heroku Apps** (change `app` to `web` in that case)

In order to mix Python (Flask) and Node you will need to install multiple buildpacks. You can let Heroku automatically detect them with `requirements.txt`, `runtime.txt` and `package.json` but it is not reliable.

This is why you should define your used buildpacks in a `app.json` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#buildpacks

```
{
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python"
    }
  ]
}
```